# UIActionSheet with non dismissing buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiactionsheet

I want to rise a  UIActionSheet with one normal "Cancel" button as usual, but with a few non-dismissing buttons, as all buttons on action sheet dismiss the sheet when touched down.
I've tried to add UIButtons using addSubView but Im having a tough time dealing with the ActionSheet size.
Any advice?

TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with a UIActionSheet.

You could however create your own view that looks like an ActionSheet and add it to the View in question. Add some core animation to make it slide up and down and viola! You'd have a custom UIActionSheet!

Comment: Ty Chris. Ive found a easier solution overimposing my own UIButton over the original UIActionSheet's. I know its far from elegant but pretty much practical.